# Magento 2 problem with remote DB connection

Tags: magento2, database

I have set **host** value to use a remote IP in my **env.php** file.
But I got an error saying "Access denied for user 'manager'@'localhost'(using password: YES)"

why Magento 2 still says I'm using the localhost?

I have tested the username and password for mysql, so I'm sure they are correct.
And the mysql user I used have remote access

I have cleared the Cache, di, generation folder.

Answer (score 0):

It already happened here, maybe your database doesn't have permit to this user, to check use this command below changing the user (-u parameter), password (-p parameter), host (-h parameter) and database (-D parameter):

> mysql -u**root** -p**root** -h **127.0.0.1** -D **database**

If it doesn't work, try access with your **root** user to check.

Comment: Sorry, i edited my comments. your command works find for me if I use root. But when if I use root login in env.php. it still give me the same error.

Comment: Try to update your Magento to 2.0.13

Comment: I'm already using 2.1.0

Comment: So update to 2.1.15